# Who to update documents in collection found using $lookup $match

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

A simple version to explain my issue.

I have two collections.  I need to update the 'person' collection (club field) based on a $lookup/$match query against the 'colour' collection.

```
db.person.insertMany([
    {"name" : "john", age : 5, "club" : "apollo"},
    {"name" : "yeshua", age : 5, "club" : "apollo"},
    {"name" : "abi", age : 12, "club" : "zeus"},
    {"name" : "andre", age : 12, "club" : "zeus"},
    {"name" : "raizel", age : 7, "club" : "rhea"},
    {"name" : "zeek", age : 7, "club" : "rhea"},
]);

db.colour.insertMany([
    {"color" : "blue", age : 5},
    {"color" : "yellow", age : 12},
    {"color" : "white", age : 7},
]);
```

I am trying to do something like this...

```
db.person.aggregate([{$lookup: {from:"colour",localField:"age",foreignField:"age", as:"color"}},{$match:{"color.age":7}},{$set:{"club":"athena"}}])
```

So far the only solution that I have found is to run the aggregation and then Foreach loop over each document and individually $set the values.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MongoDB 4.2, the [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) pipeline stage allows you to write results back to a collection. Note that if you want to write back to the collection you're running the pipeline on, you'll have to use MongoDB 4.4 or later.